# Input matrices from a file

Tags: java, file, matrix

I'm trying to read 2D matrices from an input file.The​ ​input​ ​file​ ​contains​ ​a​ ​series​ ​of​ ​inputs.​ ​First​ ​line​ ​contains​ ​the matrix ​size​ ​​n.​Next​ ​​n line​ ​contains​ ​​n ​integer​ ​each,​ ​i.e.,​ ​an​ ​n*n matrix.​​The​ ​file​ ​ends with​ ​a​ ​zero​ ​as​ ​matrix ​size.A small sample is below.

2
1 1 
1 1
3
3 1 2
1 1 2
2 2 1
6
1 2 3 4 2 3
3 3 4 5 2 1
4 3 3 1 2 3
5 4 3 6 2 1
3 2 4 3 4 3
2 3 4 1 5 6
0

I wrote the following code but it doesn't show what i need.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class trial{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        //System.out.println(new File("input.txt").getAbsolutePath());

        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("./input.txt"));

        while (true){
            int n = input.nextInt();
            //System.out.println("%d",n);

            if(n!=0) {
                int[][] grid = new int[n][n];

                while (input.hasNext()) {
                    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
                        for (int column = 0; column < n; column++) {
                            grid[row][column] = input.nextInt();
                            System.out.printf(" %d    ", grid[row][column]);
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Array done");

                }
            }
            input.close();
        }

    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }

}
}
```

The code output is below.It always generates a 2*2 matrix.

1     1
 1     1
Array done

3     3
 1     2
Array done

1     1
 2     2
Array done

2     1
 6     1
Array done

2     3
 4     2
Array done

3     3
 3     4
Array done

5     2
 1     4
Array done

3     3
 1     2
Array done

3     5
 4     3
Array done

6     2
 1     3
Array done

2     4
 3     4
Array done

3     2
 3     4
Array done

1     5
 6     0
Array done

Comment: What is the error you're getting? It's difficult to analyze your code without knowing what were looking for.

Comment: Please avoid using screenshots. Provide the text of your file so people can copy it attempt to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Also, you never break out of the outermost loop if `n` *does* equal zero. Attempting to read from a close file and getting an error is a crappy way to terminate your program. For that matter, your program always terminates with an error after the first matrix, doesn't it?

Comment: post updated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it looks like you want to stop if the user inputs a size of 0, but you don't actually do that, instead you just loop forever. Second, after reading the first matrix, you close the scanner, which isn't what you should do. `input.close()` should be outside the while loop. Try this.

```
try {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("./input.txt"));
    int n;

    while (input.hasNextInt() && (n = input.nextInt()) > 0) {
        int[][] grid = new int[n][n];

        for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
            for (int column = 0;
                     column < n && input.hasNextInt(); column++) {
                grid[row][column] = input.nextInt();
                System.out.printf("a %d    ", grid[row][column]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("Array done");
    }
    input.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File not found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are not check when the nextInt is a size and when is a number in matrix . Another thing is that a 0 in size it is for you an EOF , so you shoul get out .

Below a working example :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("pathtofile"));

        while (true){
            int n = input.nextInt();
            //System.out.println("%d",n);
            int cont =0;
            if(n!=0) {
                int[][] grid = new int[n][n];

                while (input.hasNext() && cont != n) {
                    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
                        for (int column = 0; column < n; column++) {
                            grid[row][column] = input.nextInt();
                            System.out.printf("a %d    ", grid[row][column]);
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                        cont++;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Array done");

                }
            }
            else{
            input.close();
            break;
            }

        }
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }

}}
```

Result :

[image]